# Core dump and IPC package

Tags: c, semaphore

I have small problem with the program. I do not know why when you start the program pops `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
My code for client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define receiveKey 21
#define sendKey 11

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char msg[512];
    strcpy(msg, argv[1]);
    key_t key;
    key=ftok("/Downloads/zad6", getpid());

    int senQueue=msgget(sendKey,0777);
    int recQueue=msgget(receiveKey,0777);

    msgsnd(senQueue,&msg,strlen(msg),0);
    msgrcv(recQueue,&msg,sizeof(msg),0,0);

    printf("Translate result: %s\n", msg);
    return 0;    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running your program with a debugger (like `gdb`)?

Comment: if argv[1] is more than 512 characters long, you will get a stack overflow and your program will crash. you also should be checking the return value of ftok, msgsnd, and msgrcv.

Comment: Since you don't use `key`, I don't think that's what causes the segfault, but `key=ftok("/Downloads/zad6", getpid());` unless you really have a "Downloads" directory in "/", that will fail.

Comment: @user931794 argv[1] doesn't accept functions, crash is when start the client. daniel-fischer You can be right. How to create ftok when my location to client is /home/dawid/Downloads/zad6 ? its example

Comment: @newbieprogrammer argv[1] is the "argument vector." it contains the first commandline argument passed to the program. it accepts a string. if that string is too long, the program will crash.